# EntityFramework 5 Code First - lookup table gets duplicate records

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am trying the EF5 CodeFirst and cannot get the simple setup to work ;(

I have two classes Foo and Bar where Bar represent lookup table.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }

}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }

    public MyDbContext(): base("testEF"){}

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have created a static class that serves as DataAccess Layer - in real-world application it will be on different physical tier

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public static Bar GetBarById(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return db.Bars.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public static Foo InsertFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            db.Foos.Add(foo);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I am initializing the DB with seed method:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<testEF.MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
    protected override void Seed(testEF.MyDbContext context)
    {
            context.Bars.AddOrUpdate(
                new Bar { Description = "Bar_1" },
                new Bar { Description = "Bar_2" }

                );
    }
}
```

This creates two records in Bars table. So far so good...

Here is my Main function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bar1 = DataAccess.GetBarById(1); 

    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Name = "Foo_1",
        Bar = bar1
    };

    DataAccess.InsertFoo(foo);

}
```

After the app runes there is a record in the Foos table:

```
Id       Name    Bar_Id
1        Foo_1   3
```

Why Bar_Id is 3? The EF actually inserted new record to Bars table!

```
Id  Description
1   Bar_1
2   Bar_2
3   Bar_1
```

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I have found a workaround - to attach Bar property prior to inserting the record:

```
public static Foo InsertFoo(Foo foo)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        db.Bars.Attach(foo.Bar);

        db.Foos.Add(foo);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

It is working now but this is more like a hack than a valid solution...
In real-world application the complexity of the objects could become a huge problem. 
I am open to better solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `bar1` comes from a different data context. Your `InsertFoo` method implicitly adds it to the second context by building a relationship with the `Foo`. You want these two to share a context. So use a single context for the whole scope of the `Main` method.

Comment: +1 for you. i think you are very right.and i think he must setup a foreign key between two table as well.

Comment: I cannot have data access code on the client side.  Let say my shared DataAccess class is WCF service. I cannot believe the EF is not suitable for large distributed applications.

Comment: @MichaelD. Assuming it's a WCF service, what you would want to do is create a context when the request begins and make sure all your WCF methods use that context (usually by storing it in the `HttpContext`).  This is common technique that is employed also by projects like nHibernate.

Comment: Michael, I didn't tell you to have data access code on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity you mention (which I agree with you) is caused by using a static class for your data access component.  It forces you to separate your DBContext's across method calls.  Instead of doing it that way, why not create a normal class, and build the context in the constructor.

With this, you don't need to attach foo.Bar anymore.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    private MyDbContext _context;

    public DataAccess(){
        _context = new MyDbContext();
    }

    public Bar GetBarById(int id)
    {
        return _context.Bars.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
    }

    public Foo InsertFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        _context.Foos.Add(foo);

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return foo;
    }
}
```

There are many ways you can build on and enhance this.  You could create an interface for MyDbContext called `IDbContext` and using a DI framework inject it into this class.  Similarly, you could do the same for the `DataAccess` class and inject that into wherever it's needed.